# we advocated from the outset

Tags: word-usage

Is the word "advocated" here neutral? Is the word usually a bit negative (because it makes me link it to commercial advertisement).

> “Because we were very alarmed by the geopolitical tensions between major powers, **we advocated from the outset** for global solidarity,” says Tedros in an e-mail to Nature.

> Source:  Nature  [Nature’s 10: ten people who helped shape science in 2020](https://www.nature.com/immersive/d41586-020-03435-6/index.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To "advocate" is to argue for something. a lawyer advocates for a client, a lobbyist for a client, a supporter advocates for a cause. When the advocacy seems biased or dishonest or extreme it may be thought of as negative, when it seems impassioned and well directed, it may be thought of as positive. The word itself does not imply either a positive nor a negative sense.

In this case the author is saying that the author, Tedros , argued for global solidarity, For those who are also in favor of global solidarity, this might be seen as good. Tedros  gives the reasons why s/he and others took the position they did: “Because we were very alarmed by the geopolitical tensions between major powers". Presumably if there is global solidarity there will be no reason for tensions between major powers and perhaps less reason for war and other bad things. That seems to have been the view of Tedros,  at least.